# How do I include model in Django Model Serializer?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, serialization, django-models

Let's say I have this model and serializer:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    data_url = models.TextField(unique=True)

class AnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = '__all__'
```

If I run:

```
animal = Animal.objects.filter(id=1).first()
data = serializers.serialize("json", animal)
```

I get a json string that looks like this:

```
[{"model": "zoo.animal", "pk": 1, "fields": {"id": "1", "sound": "woof"}]
```

Now if I run:

```
animal = Animal.objects.filter(id=1).first()
animal_serialized = AnimalSerializer(animal)
animal = JSONRenderer().render(animal.data)
```

I get a json string that looks like this:

```
b'[{"id":1,"sound":"woof"}]'
```

However, this json string is missing the "model" and "pk" and "fields" dictionaries, its just the fields. How to get make my AnimalSerializer return this data as well, as it does when I run serializers.serialize("json", animal)?

Comment: What's wrong with `serializers.serialize` method?

Comment: I need to add depth to my serialization, my model.Serializer class lets me pass the depth = 3 parameter